# Homework: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: java

Okay so I have a homework assignment.  I thought I had everything good on it, and I am getting an

`"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at HW3.main<HW3.java:18>`

That line is:

```
tempMembers[i/4].setFirstName(args[i]);
```

Now I am still pretty much a noob at programming, and everything up until this point I have done was in Eclipse.  This program was to be created in a text editor and then compiled and ran at the command prompt.  I do not know if maybe I am just inputting the arguments incorrectly or what not.

So for this error my command prompt entry was

```
java HW3 Bill Smith 2009 Football Jane Doe 2000 Tennis David Jones 1995 Baseball
```

So is the error in my code or in my input?  And if the error is in my code can you point me in the correct direction?  Like I said command line arguments are completely new to me, and my class doesn't do examples of any of this, just talks about concepts.

```
public class HW3 {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length % 4 != 0) {
            throw new Exception(
                    "First Name, Last Name, Year Inducted, Sport not entered correctly");
        }

        HallOfFame hallOfFameList = new HallOfFame();
        hallOfFameList.setNumberOfMembers(args.length / 4);

        HallOfFameMember[] tempMembers = new HallOfFameMember[args.length / 4];


        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 4) {
            tempMembers[i/4].setFirstName(args[i]);
            tempMembers[i/4].setLastName(args[i+1]);
            tempMembers[i/4].setYearInducted(Integer.parseInt(args[i+2]));
            tempMembers[i/4].setSport(args[i+3]);
        }

        hallOfFameList.setMembers(tempMembers);
        HallOfFameMember[] sortedMembers = null;
        hallOfFameList.sortMembers(sortedMembers);
        HallOfFame.printReport(sortedMembers);


    }


}


public class HallOfFameMember implements Comparable<HallOfFameMember> {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String sport;
    private int yearInducted;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSport() {
        return sport;
    }

    public void setSport(String sport) {
        this.sport = sport;
    }

    public int getYearInducted() {
        return yearInducted;
    }

    public void setYearInducted(int yearInducted) {
        this.yearInducted = yearInducted;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(HallOfFameMember o) {

        return this.getYearInducted() - o.getYearInducted();
    }

}


public class HallOfFame {
    private HallOfFameMember[] members;
    private int numberOfMembers;

    public HallOfFameMember[] getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    public void setMembers(HallOfFameMember[] members) {
        this.members = members;
    }

    public int getNumberOfMembers() {
        return numberOfMembers;
    }

    public void setNumberOfMembers(int numberOfMembers) {
        this.numberOfMembers = numberOfMembers;
    }

    public void sortMembers(HallOfFameMember[] sortedMembers) {

        boolean bool = true;
        HallOfFameMember temp;

        while (bool) {

            bool = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < sortedMembers.length - 1; i++) {
                if (sortedMembers[i].compareTo(sortedMembers[i + 1]) > 0) {
                    temp = sortedMembers[i];
                    sortedMembers[i] = sortedMembers[i + 1];
                    sortedMembers[i + 1] = temp;
                    bool = true;

                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void printReport(HallOfFameMember[] print) {
        System.out.println("Java Sports Hall of Fame Inductees\n\n");
        System.out.printf("%-30s\t%-30s\t%-30s\n", "Name", "Year Inducted",
                "Sport");
        for (int i = 0; i < print.length; i++)
            System.out.printf("%-30s\t%-30s\t%-30s\n", print[i].getLastName()
                    + "," + print[i].getFirstName(),
                    print[i].getYearInducted(), print[i].getSport());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You initialised your array on this line:

```
HallOfFameMember[] tempMembers = new HallOfFameMember[args.length / 4];
```

but the array will contain `null` elements.  You need to construct each element in the array before you try to call methods on it:

```
tempMembers[i/4] = new HallOfFameMember();
tempMembers[i/4].setFirstName(args[i]);
```

Answer (score 3):

When you declare `tempMembers`, you initialize the *array* but not the *elements*. Add this to your `for` loop:

```
tempMembers[i / 4] = new HallOfFameMember();
```

Then you'll get another `NPE` because `sortedMembers` is null (as you are explicitly setting it to be).

I also notice some other strange areas in your code. For example, in `HallOfFame#sortMembers(HallOfFameMember[])`, why do you use a while loop that will run exactly once in any condition (setting `bool` to true beforehand and false during the loop)?

Change the last four lines to :

```
hallOfFameList.setMembers(tempMembers);
final HallOfFameMember[] sortedMembers = tempMembers;
hallOfFameList.sortMembers(tempMembers);
HallOfFame.printReport(sortedMembers);
```

to resolve the last exception and get the desired output.

Comment: Thank you. I got the sort error.   Not sure exactly what you mean about the bool.  But I did get an error.  And your code fixed it.  I had to write my own sort method.  And I figured the way I set it up would work.  Ill give it another look to make sense of it.  Thank you again

Comment: Sure thing! This is a help site, after all. Sorry about the boolean thing; I misunderstood the code. I hope your assignment works out!

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that `tempMembers[i/4]` evaluates to `null`, and when you try to call a method on null, you get a NullPointerException. In this case, you're getting it because you haven't actually put anything into `tempMembers` yet. In Java, creating an array doesn't populate it. Creating the array with `new HallOfFameMember[args.length / 4]` creates a new array of some length with all of its positions set to `null`. So after creating the array, you need to create and store a new `HallOfFameMember` in each array position.